# i want to override the value of lat and lng variable in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
    export class test implements OnInit {

    lat = 1; 
    lng = 2;
```

this lat, lng not accessible in the showPosition function

I want to access this lat, lng in showPosition Function

```
 ngOnInit() {
  let lat2 : any;
  let lng2 : any;
 function getLocation() {
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
 } else {
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
 }
}
 function showPosition(position) {
  lat2 = position.coords.latitude;
  lng2 = position.coords.longitude;
  console.log(this.lat);
}

getLocation();
console.log(lat2);
 }
 }
```

//this lat2, lng2 not accessible outside the showPosition function

output

Cannot read properties of null

undefined

Comment: console.log(this.lat2); do like this. add a this operator on lat2 and lat2.

Comment: TRIED its shows error : Property 'lat2' does not exist

Comment: `console.log(this.lat)` and `console.log(this.lng)` try this.

Comment: Tried not working showing Cannot read properties of null

Comment: I think the error is from `position.coords`, it may be it null. Try it to write on the console.

Comment: checked its not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is your first time dealing with asynchronous calls. It takes time to get a response, so you can't just use the data immediately. Basically you have three options to handle them: `Callbacks`, `Promises`, or `Observables`.

**Callback** - put everything you want to do in a callback function - this is the old way.

```js
  lat = 1;
  lng = 2;
  lat2: any;
  lng2: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    const getLocation = () => {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
        alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
      }
    };
    const showPosition = (position: any) => {
      this.lat2 = position.coords.latitude;
      this.lng2 = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(this.lat);
      console.log(this.lat2);
    };

    getLocation();
  }
```

**Promise** - used with `async` and `await` - this makes the code look more synchronous

```js
  lat = 1;
  lng = 2;
  lat2: any;
  lng2: any;

  async ngOnInit() {
    const getLocation = async () =>
      new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: any) => {
            this.lat2 = position.coords.latitude;
            this.lng2 = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log(this.lat);
            resolve();
          });
        } else {
          alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
          reject();
        }
      });

    await getLocation();
    console.log(this.lat2);
  }
```

**Observables** - you can subscribe to these with more callback functions, this is the most popular way and relies on the RXJS library. You're going to need to learn these if ever you use the `HttpClient` Angular service for performing http requests.

```js
  lat = 1;
  lng = 2;
  lat2: any;
  lng2: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    const getLocation$ = new Observable((observer) => {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: any) => {
          this.lat2 = position.coords.latitude;
          this.lng2 = position.coords.longitude;
          console.log(this.lat);
          observer.next(position);
          observer.complete();
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
        observer.complete();
      }
    });

    getLocation$.subscribe((position: any) => {
      console.log(this.lat2);
    });
  }
```

These are just rough examples but hopefully that gets you on the right track.

Forgot to mention the useful extension of an Observable - **Subject**

```js
  lat = 1;
  lng = 2;
  lat2: any;
  lng2: any;
  subject = new Subject<any>();

  ngOnInit() {
    const getLocation = () => {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position: any) => {
          this.lat2 = position.coords.latitude;
          this.lng2 = position.coords.longitude;
          console.log(this.lat);
          this.subject.next(position);
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
      }
    };

    getLocation();
    this.subject.subscribe((position) => console.log(this.lat2));
  }
```

Comment: Nope showing same error brother :(

Comment: I edited slightly since I saw you wanted some variables inside `ngOnInit`. Both methods work fine for me.

Comment: Still unable to get lat2 output but got lat output now

Comment: Well `lat2` is of course undefined because you never called `showPosition()`

Comment: still unable to access lat2

Comment: For whatever reason, you've put this code inside a function. The code inside functions do not get executed until you call the function....

Comment: I tried after execute function still am getting error

Comment: after execution am having error at showPosition function in lat2 Cannot read properties of undefined

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't realize this is an asynchronous call with a callback function, the data won't be available until after the call completes, which takes time. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I also tried      this.zone.onStable.subscribe(_ => {
                       this.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                       this.lng = position.coords.longitude;
                      }

Comment: I've updated my answer, you are going to do need to some research to understand asynchronous programming.

Comment: Thanks its worked , u r life saver :)

Comment: no problem, I added the `subject` as well - probably the most useful one.

Comment: Thank u so much, and yes I am new to angular jus started this week and I knw abt async but i jus didn't realize it at first, thanks Chris Hamilton :)